# return penultimate value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to return the penultimate record of a field? I want to do a select that would return me 2 ... Always the second but last record of the field

I use

```
select top(1) u_lastdado from (select top 2 u_lastdado from cl order by u_lastdado desc ) t order by u_lastdado asc
```

but doesn't work. He continues to give me the present value and not the old

Example

```
select u_lastdado from cl where u_lastdado<> ''
```

> u_lastdado
>
> 243237000
>  213968131

```
update cl set u_lastdado=213968126 where nome ='Eira e Beira, lda'
```

> u_lastdado
>
> 243237000
>  213968126

I need to know how to go get the '213968131' that was formerly
I use SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028651/return-penultimate-record-of-a-field

Comment: there is no sql query that would get you the records value before it was updated.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to update the table and the retrieve the value that was in the table before you did the update? Unless you have an audit table with historical values this is impossible because the value has changed.

Comment: WOW....just wow....just looked at the link from @jarlh Didn't like the response so created a second account and posted the same useless question.

Comment: @SeanLange lately I saw many users that post the same question twice, even if they accepted an answer on the first one ... smh

Comment: But your first question got closed because the question is not clear. Then you created a new account and posted the same question. Your question is poor because you didn't provide us enough detail. We can't see your screen or read your mind. The only thing I can gain from both questions is you want to be able to retrieve data that is no longer in the table which isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to return the penultimate record of a field?

Not the way you mean it, no.  It is not possible.